# Add multiple child elements with different values in the same request body

Tags: jmeter

How to add multiple child elements with different values in the same JMeter post request body?

I will need to add 1000 of these. Please see below HTTP Request Body data.
Thanks

```
[
    {
        "action": "create",
        "uniqueId": "${uniqueId1}",
        "value": {
            "name": "Bulk Create ${uniqueId1}",
            "notes": "Created on ${__time(DDMMYYYY,)}",
            "pmaPrefix": "ABC",
            "uniqueId": "${uniqueId1}"
        }
    },
    {
        "action": "create",
        "uniqueId": "${uniqueId2}",
        "value": {
            "name": "Bulk Create ${uniqueId2}",
            "notes": "Created on ${__time(DDMMYYYY,)}",
            "pmaPrefix": "ABC",
            "uniqueId": "${uniqueId2}"
        }
    },
    {
        "action": "create",
        "uniqueId": "${uniqueId3}",
        "value": {
            "name": "Bulk Create ${uniqueId3}",
            "notes": "Created on ${__time(DDMMYYYY,)}",
            "pmaPrefix": "ABC",
            "uniqueId": "${uniqueId3}"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate whatever number of elements you want using any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

Example code:

```
def payload = []
def entry = [:]

1.upto(1000, index -> {
    entry.put('action', 'create')
    def uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    entry.put('uniqueId', 'uniqueId')
    def value = [:]
    value.put('name', 'Bulk Create ' + uniqueId)
    value.put('notes', 'Created on ' + new Date().format('DDMMYYYY'))
    value.put('pmaPrefix', 'ABC')
    value.put('uniqueId', uniqueId)
    entry.put('value', value)
    payload.add(entry)
})

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

Assuming everything goes well you should be able to refer the generated content as `${payload}` where required.

More information:

- [JsonBuilder documentation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)